# Maven: download source from github, compile into jar, include jar in WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: java, maven, jar, include

There are many "solutions" to this issue which I have tried to no avail, so please forgive me if this seems redundant.

I have a Java/Maven project being built with Intellij IDEA which has a dependency on the jar file built from this GitHub project: https://github.com/protegeproject/snap-sparql-query

Unfortunately, the jar is NOT in any external repository so must be built by me. I have the build working and manually copy the jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder of my parent project. Intellij then runs correctly, all dependent jars are found at execution even though the resulting war file does not contain the snap-sparql-query jar. I'm guessing it is getting cached somewhere.

If I build the project from the command line (`$ mvn clean package`) it builds but the above jar file still is NOT included in the resulting war file, even if it exists in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the parent before being packaged as a war file.

The ideal solution would be Maven commands in the parent that:

1. download the source for snap-sparql-query
2. compile the source into a jar
3. copy the jar to the parent WEB-INF/lib directory
4. all jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory get included in the war file

At the *very least* I'd be satisfied manually performing items 1-3 above, but have Maven perform #4.

Here is the Maven entry for snap-sparql-query:

```
<!-- SNAP SPARQL API -->
<!-- https://github.com/protegeproject/snap-sparql-query -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
    <artifactId>snap-sparql-query-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- this library isn't found in the maven repository, must be externally compiled -->
    <!-- and copied to the ...WEB-INF/lib directory so this pom can find it -->
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/WEB-INF/lib/snap-sparql-query-api-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
    <artifactId>de-derivo-sparqldlapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <!--<version>3.0.0</version>-->
</dependency>
```

I've been warned using the systemPath is *bad*, so I would like to avoid that too, if possible.

Can I have Maven perform at least item 4 above, and/or ideally 1-4?

Comment: It appears this question got downgraded without an explanation why. Please explain the reason for the downgrade, I honestly want to know. It may help me solve my problem.

Comment: Clone the project and make `mvn clean install` and add this dependency to your project and build it afterwards...

Comment: @KennyCason Is this a hobby project or your enterprise project? If this is for your enterprise, is your organization uses any CI tools such as Jenkins, Bamboo etc.? Also is your organization uses any Artifactory Repository Management system such as [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Nexus Repo Manager](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss)?

Comment: This is not an enterprise project nor hobby, but a contract project for which I have little or no control over the customer's environment. Hence the hope for a turnkey solution. Having said that, the post below pretty much sums up what I eventually had to do. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You asked multiple things and in order to answer all, I need more
>   details. I will update the answer once you provide those details. But for now, below is the answer for the Item 4 in your list.

By default Maven will not include System scoped jars in the packaged application. In order to include System scoped dependencies you need to use maven-dependency-plugin's copy- dependency goal.

Please note the `<phase>prepare-package</phase>`. Having phase `prepare-package` is very important to include the dependencies in the WAR file since this goal needs to be executed before the execution of maven-war-plugin.

```
<build>
        <finalName>maven-sys-scope</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dep</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>system</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```